# getComputedStyle() not working in IE8

Tags: jquery

I have the getComputedStyle() function in my script page . But its does not work in IE8.

```
My code :- 

    var isDesktop = window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').getPropertyValue('content');
```

Error :- 
          Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: the newest jquery does not support IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Right, `getComputedStyle` doesn't exist in early IE. If you weren't looking for the style of a pseudo-element, you could use ID's `currentStyle`:

```
var style = document.body.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(document.body);
```

...(and then use the properties on `style`), but IE has no equivalent of the ability to choose pseudo-elements. Instead (and this is ugly), you have to loop through the style rules in the loaded stylesheets, figure out which ones apply to the element in question, and figure out the pseudo-element content from the rule's styles.

**Example:** *(I would have used a Stack Snippet, but they don't work on IE8; [here it is on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xunarifemi/))*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var style = document.body.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(document.body);
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<p>Color: " + style.color + "</p>"
  );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, though, that won't give you pseudo-element properties.

Comment: No I got  error in here .if (isDesktop.indexOf('smallscreen') == -1 && isDeviceMobile() == null) {  }

Comment: @kannan: There is no `isDesktop` in my answer. My answer tells you how to get a `style` object for the element. As it says in the answer: *"..and then use the properties on `style`..."* But again, you're not trying to get it from a pseudo-element anymore, right?

Comment: style .indexOf('smallscreen') == -1 ,here i got   Object expected

Comment: @kannan: What makes you think `style` is a string? Is the return value from `getComputedStyle` a string? No? Then why would the `style` in the above be? Did you *look* at the live, working example?